# Data structure that quickly get multiple min(max) elements C++

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I'm trying to store some elements into a container and would like to get it efficiently based on some criteria.

To put it simple, suppose:

1. the record is like: (ID, Age, Wage)
2. for each insert and delete it returns a sum of wage for the minimal age

Like following

```
       ID  Age Wage(k)
insert 1   23  95   // returns 23,95
insert 2   21  75   // returns 21,75
insert 3   27  85   // returns 21,75
insert 4   21  65   // returns 21,140
delete ID=2         // returns 21,65
```

There are several solutions that I can think of:

*1. Vector (boost::circular_buffer?)*

```
e.g. [(23,1,95), (21,2,75), (27,3,85), (21,4,65)]
Insert: O(1)
Delete (can use a bit to mark deleted) O(n)
GetMinSum: O(n)
```

*2. Sorted vector*

```
e.g. [(21,2,75), (21,4,65), (23,1,95), (27,3,85)]
Insert: O(n)
Delete (can use a bit to mark deleted) O(n)
GetMinSum: O(1)
```

*3. Map (RB tree)*

```
std::map<age, vector<record>>
[(21)->[(2,75),(1,65)], (23)->[(1,95)], (27)->[(3,85)]]
GetMinSum: O(1)
Insert: O(logN)
Delete: O(n)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Any suggestions?" For what? Better container? Can you please clarify?

Comment: No part of this question makes any sense, including your purported algorithmic runtimes.

Comment: You can use some wrapper around std containers, and update min/max on insertion.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Suggestions of how to solve this problem to get best performance of Insert/Delete/GetMinSum

Comment: I would use a variant of #3 a class that has a data member `std::map<Age, vector<Record>>` where `struct Record { int ID; int Age; double Wage; };` and appropriate insert/delete methods that return the desired info.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Thanks. That way `GetMinSum` can normally be O(1), but once min record is deleted, will need to walk though whole array to get new min value. Can we do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to implement the calculation part of step 2 in `O(1)` using `std::map`:

```
std::map<int, int> sum_of_wages_by_age;
```

1. The map's key is `Age`.
2. The map's value is the sum of all wages of the given age.

Given that iterating over the keys of `std::map` must iterate in strict weak order, the lowest `Age` will always be the first key in the map. So, the sum of wages for the minimum age will simply be:

```
auto p=sum_of_wages_by_age.begin();

return p == sum_of_wages_by_age.end() ? 0: // Edge case, empty map
          p->second;
```

My answer concerns only with keeping track of the this map's content, so that the sum of wages of the minimal age can be quickly returned in this manner. This is completely separate from how you need to store the `<Id, Wage, Age>` records, themselves. That's a separate issue. It's up to you to figure out if you want to store them in a vector, or something else. No matter how you store them, the only purpose of `sum_of_wages_by_age` is to be able to quickly return the correct number. The subject matter at hand concerns itself only with being able to return the sum of wages for the minimal age efficiently, in this manner.

The above map, in order for this approach to work, needs to be kept updated whenever a record gets inserted and deleted. This can be done as follows.

## Adding a new `<ID, Age, Wage>` record.

In addition to storing this record, the wage simply need to be added to the map:

```
sum_of_wages_by_age[age] += wage;
```

## Removing an existing `<ID, Age, Wage>` record

This one is a little bit more exciting.

```
auto p=sum_of_wages_by_age.find(age);

if ( (p->second -= wage) == 0)
    sum_of_wages_by_age.erase(p);
```

You want to be tidy. After removing the last record for the given age, you want to now completely remove the entry for that age from this map. If you don't care about that, you can simply do

```
sum_of_wages_by_age[age] -= wage;
```

Note that because the record being removed must've been previously added, you're guaranteed that a map will have an entry for the age. This will only work, of course, if `wage` cannot be zero, or negative. But that's a safe assumption. As you know, there's a law that says what the minimum wage must be.

## Caveat

The above examples use `int`s for wages. If you need to use `float`s or `double`s, roundoff errors will accumulate during the repeated additions and subtractions. If this is an issue, researching how to correctly handle roundoff errors will be your homework assignment.

Comment: Looks like a good solution. Besides your `std::map`, I'm thinking of using `unordered_map` with `id->(record)` to store records, that way we have O(1) insert and delete.

Comment: And how do you expect to easily find the minimum key in the unordered_map, in O(1)?

Comment: The minimums are already stored in your `std::map`. That is, I'd need one map and one unordered_map.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no standard container that meet your requirement, but it shouldn't be to hard to write your own adaptor class.

The class could contain a vector for the actual data, a vector of pointers or references to the structures with the current minimum age, the current minimum age itself as a stack, and a map containing age->sum mapping.

- Adding data:

  When adding a new structure, you compare the current minimum age (top of the age stack), if it's larger than the current minimum then just add it to the data vector and update the sum in the age->sum mapping.

  If the age is equal to the current minimum age, add the data and update the age->sum map.

  If the age of the newly added data is smaller than the current minimum, add it to the data vector, push the new age onto the stack, and add a new entry to the age->sum map.
- Removing data:

  For all data remove it from the vector, and update the age->sum map.

  If the age is equal to the current minimum age, and the sum in the age->sum mapping have reached zero, then pop the age stack. The new sum is the sum from the new age in the age->sum map.

By using a map that you continuously update, and a stack of the minimum ages, you don't have to recount the sums as they will always by up to date.

Comment: For adding data and if age is larger than current minimum, I guess still need to add it into the minimum stack, and it's not very convenience for a stack to do so

Comment: @Deqing Hmm, that's true. Should teach me not to answer questions to early before breakfast then. :) It's true and will be a problem if the age isn't in the stack already. I'll think a little more about this during the day and see if I can figure something out. Anyway, this (and the answer from Sam) should be good starting points hopefully.

Comment: @Deqing You don't actually need the stack. [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is ordered on the key, which in my algorithm is the age. The lowest age (smallest key) will always be the first pair in the map, and the oldest (highest) will always be the last. So simply skip the stack and keep the map, it will keep track of both the sums and the lowest age.